# Defining extra implementation specific functions in a class implementing an abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, abstract, abstraction

Let's say I'm creating an abstract class Fruit with function eat() and I want to make a few different classes implementing it. However, for the class Kiwi I also want to make a function peel() which wasn't defined in my abstract class.

Is it bad practice to make extra functions in a class implementing an abstract class? 
I know I could add it to the abstract class and just have it do nothing in the classes that don't use it, but seems bad if I have a lot of other classes it won't be useful in it.

Comment: `make extra functions in a class implementing an abstract class` No, it's not a bad practice, and it's a very natural thing to do. `add it to the abstract class and just have it do nothing in the classes that don't use it` this is (usually) a bad practice; you can see some examples of it, e.g. Iterators in java: all of them has method `remove`, which is in many cases not implemented. The better approach would be to have Iterator and MutableIterator (with remove), as Kotlin does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to make extra functions in a class implementing an abstract class?

Not at all!

Suppose we have the following classses:

```cpp
class Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void Eat() = 0;    // pure virtual functions make the class abstract
}

class Berry : public Fruit
{
public:
    void Eat() override
    { /* eat the berry... */ }
}

class Kiwi : public Fruit
{
public:
    void Eat() override
    { /* eat the kiwi... */ }

    void Peel()
    { /* peel the kiwi... */ }
}
```

We can certainly `Eat()` any `Fruit` we come across so it makes sense that all `Fruit` objects can be eaten.

You wouldn't `Peel()` a `Berry` before eating it so there is no expectation that a `Berry` can be `Peel()`ed. That would be unnecessary for users that are handling a `Berry` object anyways.

Before `Eat()`ing a `Kiwi` you should `Peel()` it first, so anyone who is handling a `Kiwi` object is going to expect the `Peel()` function to be available and therefore `Peel()` their `Kiwi` before they `Eat()` it.

Now let's say the user is blindfolded and given a `Fruit* someFruit` pointer. They don't know whether it's a `Berry` or a `Kiwi` but they can certainly `try { Eat(); }` it anyways because eating fruit always makes sense! If the `Fruit` was actually a `Kiwi` and they did not `Peel()` it first then it is a good idea to have the `Kiwi::Eat()` function throw an exception (`throw "yuk!"`) or handle this unexpected usage gracefully.

Although this example is written really specifically about eating fruit, we can generally assume that the user of an object will know what functions are available for that object simply by knowing its type. And when the user does not know the object's type, then it is a good idea to implement some error-checking to handle its functions being used incorrectly.